# How to trigger API on inserting a record in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

We are looking for an option where we want to trigger an AWS API (internally calls lambda) as soon as insert is done in AWS RedShipt table. And based on the API response we want to update same record with additional info. What is the right way to do it on AWS?

Flow:
Insert into Redshift table > Trigger API (lambda) > Lambda fetches additional information > add additional info to same record which is inserted

Comment: I don't recommend using Redshift if you're planning on inserting records one at a time in this way, it's really not designed with that in mind. A row based RDBMS like Aurora might be a better option for a solution like this.

Comment: This make sense. Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Perhaps a lambda that polls for new rows on your table, and then runs whatever you want once it detects a new row might work here.  Not real time, it would only be as quick as the frequency that you schedule the lambda.  The lambda would need a way to detect 'new' rows, so that might need a secondary table or column to track when an insert has been processed.

Answer (score -4):

Use the Simple Notification Service (SNS) to execute a Lambda function when a record is inserted into Redshift table.

Comment: How would you have Redshift send an SNS message?

Comment: By using the row insertion event in SNS.

Comment: Please link to some sort of documentation that shows SNS has a "row insertion event" for Amazon Redshift databases.

Comment: I’m just guessing over here. There must be a similar mechanism available to do this